# The name VARname does not exist in the current context C#

Tags: c#, listbox, visual-studio-2019

I know there are a lot of similar questions/answers but I was not able to adapt a solution from those to my problem:

I'm trying to iterate, loop through the items of a listbox (all elements are paths) and I would like to open them all with the default windows program with the click of button. Any help would be much appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is the semicolon after the `foreach` statement. The semicolon ends the foreach statement immediately. The code you have above is equivalent to:

```cs
foreach (string myitem in this.listBox1.Items)
{
  // myitem is only available in this scope
}

MessageBox.Show(myitem.toString(), "My Caption", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(myitem.ToString());
```

You need to encapsulate everything you want in the foreach in a scope like so:

```cs
foreach (string myitem in this.listBox1.Items)
{
  MessageBox.Show(myitem.toString(), "My Caption", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
  System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(myitem.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Many thanks, I really appreciate it, this solved it :)